# Как сделать выпадающий список в php, данные из mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Как сделать рядом с полем для заполнения выпадающий список, который будет показывать данные с другой таблицы и при нажатии записвыать их в поле?

```
<form method="kolstud" action="kolstud.php">
<input name="namebook" ty0ё="int" value="наименование книги"/>
  <input name="FIOstud" type="int" value="ФИО студента"/>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Добавить"/>
</form>//поля для данных

$namebook = $_REQUEST['namebook'];
$FIOstud = $_REQUEST['FIOstud'];

$insert = "INSERT INTO `kolstud` VALUES (
  ( SELECT `idbook` FROM `book` WHERE `name` = '$namebook' ),
  ( SELECT `idstudent` FROM `student` WHERE `FIO` = '$FIOstud' )
)";//запрос на добавление
```

Comment: Что вы пожразумеваете под "выпадающим списком"?

ul li?

Comment: Может быть `<select ...>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="book">
    <option value="0">Выберите книгу</option>
<?
$res = mysql_query('select `id`, `name` from `books`');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['name']?></option>
    <?
}
?>
</select>
```

Примерно так. А почему у вас input type="int"?
А если вы хотите сделать кнопочку как в Joomla, с помощью css поместите текстовое поле над select'ом, чтобы торчала только стрелка.

**Добавлено**
Изменил код.

Comment: Слегка поменял код. Студент добавляется по аналогии.

Comment: а) Поменяйте название полей и таблиц на ваши.  
б) Наполните таблицы чем-нибудь.

Comment: Значит, у вас ошибка где-то вне этого кода. Например, нет соединения с БД. Включите отображение ошибок и посмотрите. Или же почитайте журнал ошибок.

Comment: Открываем редактор -> добавляем... ^.^