# Выпадающее меню из MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Как реализовать выпадающее меню с данными из mysql?

К примеру, у меня есть вот такой HTML код меню

```
<li>                        
    <span>Транспот</span>                           
    <ul> 
            <li><a href="#">Самолет</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Поезд</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Автобус</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Автомобиль</a></li>                                     
    </ul>
</li>
```

Сначала идет основной раздел, т.е. родительский элемент меню, а после идут дочерние элементы меню.

структура базы выглядит так:

```
id, menutitle,  link, parent
```

тут, думаю, тоже особо ничего не надо объяснять, всего лишь уделю внимание на колонку parent, где будет храниться ID родительского элемента.

Как вывести это всё из базы в виде вышеуказанного HTML кода?

Comment: та собственно ни чего сложного, обычный while т.е цикл и в этом цикле выводим некую переменную-массив ну и всё собственно...самой ссылкой служит id это собственно не сложно хотя есть над чем потрудится особенно когда не умеешь пользоваться поисковиками ...

Comment: хоть и вопрос дубликат но я всё таки : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/56927/308974

Comment: http://admin-gu.ru/php/drop-down-list-php-mysql  здесь надо только mysql заменить на mysqli или pdo ...

Answer (score 2):

Как то так, в массиве($array) должны быть данные из БД:

```
<li>                        
    <span>Транспот</span>                           
    <ul> 
    <?php foreach($array as $item) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?= $item['id'] ?>"><?= $item['menutitle'] ?></a></li>  
    <?php } ?>                                 
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: ссылку тоже надо было вывести - а то появится следующий вопрос

Comment: ну это же пример, ссылку добавил

Comment: плюсик от меня.

Comment: По моему вы не понял вопрос ) Имела ввиду чтоб и дочерний элемент выводилось из базы т е само слово транспорт тоже будет выводится из базы а насчет того что вы показали я уже поняла даже через поисковик , спасибо

Comment: тоже самое, только установите в качестве условия id дочерней категории

Comment: а можете подробнее если можно

Comment: я конечно не знаю, что у вас в таблицах но примерно так: foreach($array as $item) { if ($item['pattern] == 1){. Но если вы работаете с 2 таблицами, то вначале перебираем 1 получаем id и вместо 1 указываем его, тогда вы получите отсортированный список

Comment: нет всё у меня в одной таблице и спасибо за ответ попробую использовать ваши подсказки )

Comment: тогда еще проще, просто условие

Comment: Товарищи никогда не слышали про рекурсию просто... зы - пример не рабочий для меню с вложеннотью более 1 уровня

Answer (score 0):

```
  function DrawMenu($id,$menu)
  {
    $result = '';
    if(isset($menu[$id]))
    {
      $result .= "<ul>";
      foreach($menu[$id] as $val)
      {
        $result .= "<li><a href='./page/".$val['id']."' >".$val['description']."</a>";
          $result .= DrawMenu($val['childs'],$menu);
        $result .= "</li>";
      }
      $result .= "</ul>";
    } 
    return $result;
  }
```

Функция реурсивного вывода меню.
Массив под такой вывод должен быть подготовлен, глубина вложенности не имеет значения.